# Como conectar JDBC (H2 Database) em PHP?

Tags: php, h2database

Como conectar um banco de dados JDBC (especificamente H2 Database) no PHP?
O banco de dados está em um único arquivo com extensão `.db`

Comment: Votei por deixar esta questão aberta, pois não é algo tão simples de se fazer (ao menos até aonde pesquisei) e por mais que a pergunta soe como "ampla" na verdade não é fácil de encontrar por "onde começar".

Comment: Na verdade não acho que soe como ampla. Só é dificil achar algo relacionado ao assunto.

Comment: Na verdade o meu comentário não foi pra ti, você recebeu 4 votos de fechamento na pergunta como sendo *ampla demais*, eu coloquei o comentário em uma área chamada fila de analise, pra outros que verem a sua questão pensarem antes de fechar. É mais um apoio pra manter a tua pergunta aberta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme o link http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html:

> PHP support: H2 should support PDO, or test with PostgreSQL PDO.
>
> Suporte ao PHP: O H2 deve dar suporte ao PDO ou faça o teste com o *PostgreSQL PDO*

Não tenho como testar aqui o H2, mas se o link estiver correto, então você pode usar o PDO pra PostgreSQL. No momento os bancos suportados pelo PDO são:

- CUBRID
- MS SQL Server
- Firebird
- IBM
- Informix
- MySQL
- MS SQL Server
- Oracle
- ODBC and DB2
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- 4D

E não há nenhum driver especifico pro *H2 Database*, mas como dito anteriormente você pode tentar o driver do *PostgreSQL*, conforme o link do próprio *H2 Database*.

Algo como:

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;user=usuario;password=senha');
```

Se isto for possível, é provável que não exista compatibilidade total e pelo que pesquisei, parece que é um trabalho muito difícil e dificilmente alguém conseguiu fazer isto.

Outro detalhe, eu não tenho certeza, mas acredito que o *h2 database* seja suportado pelo [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) e talvez possa usa-lo com PDO assim.

Fora isto você pode tentar usar o https://github.com/webdevelopersdiary/jamp que é uma plataforma *PHP independente* com suporte para bancos em java (<s>do java?</s>)

Pra configurar o jdbc com *h2 database* vá até `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` e troque a linha:

```
<Set name="url">jdbc:h2:mem:database;IGNORECASE=TRUE;MODE=MYSQL</Set>
```

para

```
<Set name="url">jdbc:h2:file:filename;IGNORECASE=TRUE;MODE=MYSQL</Set>
```

Onde você substituiu por `filename` deve ser o caminho relativo para um arquivo (em relação ao `pom.xml`) ou um caminho absoluto para um arquivo (em caso de absoluto algo como `jdbc:h2:file:c:\users\usuario\desktop\banco;IGNORECASE=TRUE;MODE=MYSQL`). Para obter mais informações sobre o *URL H2 JDBC* veja a [lista de recursos do H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url).

Mesmo que você consiga conectar, ainda sim acredito que isto não é uma boa ideia pro *ambiente de produção*, devido a prováveis instabilidades por falta de alguma compatibilidade, portanto recomendo converter o seu banco pra mysql ou outro banco suportado por padrão pelo PDO.